# Forward declaration of template class nested inside template class

Tags: c++, templates, nested

You can forward declare a template inner class inside a normal class, and use the defined type as any other forward declared type.

```
class Outer {
    template <int N> class Inner;
    typedef Inner<0> Inner0;
    Inner0* f();
};

template<int N>
class Outer::Inner {};
```

Now if Outer is itself a template class, is there a way to keep the declaration of Inner outside the declaration of Outer ? Something like :

```
template<typename T>
class Outer {
    template <int N> class Inner;
    typedef Inner<0> Inner0;
    Inner0* f();
};

template<typename T, int N> //This won't work
class Outer<T>::Inner {};
```

Is there a correct syntax to declare Outer with the right template parameters ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following

```
template<typename T>
template <int N>
class Outer<T>::Inner {};
```

According to the C++ Standard (14.5.2 Member templates)

> 1 A template can be declared within a class or class template; such a
>   template is called a member template. A member template can be defined
>   within or outside its class definition or class template definition. **A
>   member template of a class template that is defined outside of its
>   class template definition shall be specified with the
>   template-parameters of the class template followed by the
>   template-parameters of the member template.**

Comment: Oh god, it was so obvious... Thanks for the reply :)